# SVM.train_auto error opencv

Tags: android, opencv, svm, libsvm

i have a problem, when i call SVM.train_auto with opencv2.3 for android, i have an error with response matrix because this matrix format is wrong.
I watched opencv documentation, but it doesn't explain the format of response matrix.
Can anyone helps me?
I attach my code:

```
paramtriSVM = new CvSVMParams();  
matriceSVM = new CvSVM(); 
Mat responso = new Mat();  
Mat varID = new Mat();  
Mat esempiID = new Mat();  
matriceSVM.train_auto(res, responso, varID, esempiID, paramtriSVM);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responses should not be empty. For classification problems, the responses are discrete class labels of the train Data. For regression problems, the responses are values of the function to be approximated.

Answer (score 0):

As opencv documentation mentions, "automatically" means choosing the optimal parameters C , gamma , p , nu , coeff, degree from `CvSVMParams` . By optimal one means that the cross-validation estimate of the test set error is minimal.

Simple question for the beginning: is the matrix containing your training data empty, as in your code example ?

Comment: so i'm sorry for the text but: res is the input matrix and it is not empty, responoso is the response matrix and in this matrix give error. The documentation that i have read, don't give information about response matrix. OK?